# Training not happening in deep learning

Tags: keras, deep-learning, regression, layer, loss

The deep learning model is not getting trained predicting values totally out of range even for the training dataset and giving a huge negative value for the R<sup>2</sup>.

If I run the following code I get a huge negative value for the R<sup>2</sup>. The dataset is big, especially with a lot of features. This is a simplified datafile that is still able to reproduce the problem: [text](https://pastebin.com/NEgTpSae). If I run the same data with a simple linear regression or SVR algorithm I get a good value (see the next code).

I played with the parameters, mainly with the number of layers, the number of units per layer and the learning rate, with no success. I also tried to normalize the data.

With other smaller problems a similar code worked. Do you know what could be the problem? Maybe this is just not a problem for DL?

Here the deep learning model:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

var='target'

matrixpd = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0)
md=matrixpd[var]
matrixpd = matrixpd.drop(columns=var)

def build_model():
  model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=[len(matrixpd.keys())]),
#    layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1)
  ])

  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.01)

  model.compile(loss='mse',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
  return model

EPOCHS = 100

estimator = KerasRegressor(model=build_model, epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=0)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=3)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, matrixpd, md, cv=kfold, scoring='r2')
print("R2: %.2f (%.2f)" % (results.mean(), results.std()))
```

And here the linear regression model:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

var='target'

matrixpd = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0)
md=matrixpd[var]
matrixpd = matrixpd.drop(columns=var)

model = linear_model.LinearRegression()

kfold = KFold(n_splits=3)
results = cross_val_score(model, matrixpd, md, cv=kfold, scoring='r2')
print("R2: %.2f (%.2f)" % (results.mean(), results.std()))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to train a model using that data in PyTorch. The main difference from your architecture was:

1. I found that it helped to taper the channels down gradually, rather than abruptly transitioning to a 16-unit layer. There are 500 input features, and I did the following:

   Dense(out=500), ReLU, BN

   Dense(250), ReLU, BN

   Dense(125), ReLU, BN

   Dense(64), ReLU, BN

   Dense(1)

You can drop some of the batch norm (BN) and it'll still work ok based on some quick experiments.

2. I found that `RMSprop` struggled to converge, whereas `Adam` with a learning rate of `0.01` converged well.
3. I ran it for 200 epochs. The train MSE progressed as follows:

   epoch 0   | loss: 8250

   epoch 20  | loss: 7486

   epoch 40  | loss: 5677

   epoch 60  | loss: 2932

   epoch 80  | loss: 699

   epoch 100 | loss: 16

   epoch 120 | loss: 6

   epoch 140 | loss: 0.7

   epoch 160 | loss: 0.07

   epoch 180 | loss: 0.01

As you can see, it starts out relatively high for the first 60-80 epochs, afterwhich it drops sharply.

I normalised the data using the method below, but found that it didn't affect convergence much, probably because BN performs its own standardisation.

```
matrixpd_scaled = (matrixpd - matrixpd.mean(axis=0)) / matrixpd.std(axis=0)
```

For reference, my PyTorch code is:

```
import torch, torch.nn as nn

#load data and split into features/target
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0)
y = data['target'].to_numpy().ravel()
x = data.drop(columns='target')

#standardise features per channel
x_n = (x - x.mean(axis=0)) / x.std(axis=0)

torch.manual_seed(100) #for reproducible results

#Define the model. A tapered dense network.
model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(x.shape[1], 500), nn.ReLU(), nn.BatchNorm1d(500),
                      nn.Linear(500, 250), nn.ReLU(),  nn.BatchNorm1d(250),
                      nn.Linear(250, 125), nn.ReLU(),  nn.BatchNorm1d(125),
                      nn.Linear(125, 64), nn.ReLU(),  nn.BatchNorm1d(64),
                      nn.Linear(64, 1))
#optim = torch.optim.RMSprop(model.parameters(), 0.01)
optim = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), 0.01)

for epoch in range(200):
    #prediction and MSE loss
    yhat = model(torch.tensor(x_n.values).to(torch.float32))
    loss = nn.MSELoss()(yhat.ravel(), torch.tensor(y).to(torch.float32))
    
    #Backprop
    optim.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optim.step()
    if epoch % 20 == 0:
        print('epoch', epoch, '| loss:', loss.item())
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, that also worked for me even with the larger dataset. I tried to implement something equivalent with Keras and it works with this reduced dataset but not with the larger one. And, additionally, PyTorch does it much faster. I am wondering what does PyTorch that I am not doing with Keras.

Here are the final implementations with PyTorch and Keras for comparison:

PyTorch:

```
import torch, torch.nn as nn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

var='target'

#load data and split into features/target
data = pd.read_csv('dataFULL.csv', index_col=0)

train_dataset = data.sample(frac=0.7,random_state=1)
test_dataset = data.drop(train_dataset.index)

train_labels = train_dataset.pop(var)
test_labels = test_dataset.pop(var)

#Define the model. A tapered dense network.
model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(train_dataset.shape[1], 512), nn.ReLU(), nn.BatchNorm1d(512),
                      nn.Linear(512, 256), nn.ReLU(),  nn.BatchNorm1d(256),
                      nn.Linear(256, 128), nn.ReLU(),  nn.BatchNorm1d(128),
                      nn.Linear(128, 64), nn.ReLU(),  nn.BatchNorm1d(64),
                      nn.Linear(64, 1))
#optim = torch.optim.RMSprop(model.parameters(), 0.01)
optim = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), 0.01)

for epoch in range(200):
    #prediction and MSE loss
    yhat = model(torch.tensor(train_dataset.values).to(torch.float32))
    loss = nn.MSELoss()(yhat.ravel(), torch.tensor(train_labels).to(torch.float32))
    
    #Backprop
    optim.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optim.step()
    yhatt=model(torch.tensor(test_dataset.values).to(torch.float32))
    yhatt = yhatt.detach().numpy()
    score = np.corrcoef(test_labels, yhatt.reshape(test_labels.shape))

yhat = model(torch.tensor(test_dataset.values).to(torch.float32))

yhat = yhat.detach().numpy()
plt.scatter(test_labels, yhat)
plt.xlabel('True Values')
plt.ylabel('Predictions')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.axis('square')
_ = plt.plot([-1000, 1000], [-1000, 1000])

score = np.corrcoef(test_labels, yhat.reshape(test_labels.shape))
print('R=', score[0,1])
```

Keras:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

var='target'

#load data and split into features/target
data = pd.read_csv('dataFULL.csv', index_col=0)

train_dataset = data.sample(frac=0.7,random_state=0)
test_dataset = data.drop(train_dataset.index)
mean = train_dataset.mean(axis=0)
train_dataset -= mean
std = train_dataset.std(axis=0)
train_dataset /= std
test_dataset -= mean
test_dataset /= std

train_labels = train_dataset.pop(var)
test_labels = test_dataset.pop(var)

def build_model():
  model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())]),
    layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1)
  ])

#  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.01)
  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01)
    
  model.compile(loss='mse',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['mse'])
  return model

model = build_model()

EPOCHS = 200

history = model.fit(
  train_dataset, train_labels,
  epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=0)

test_predictions = model.predict(test_dataset).flatten()

test_labels *= std[var]
test_labels += mean[var]
test_predictions *= std[var]
test_predictions += mean[var]

plt.scatter(test_labels, test_predictions)
plt.xlabel('True Values')
plt.ylabel('Predictions')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.axis('square')
_ = plt.plot([-1000, 1000], [-1000, 1000])

score = np.corrcoef(test_labels, test_predictions)
print("R =",score[0,1])
```

Comment: It seems as though you have batchnorm in the Pytorch version, but not in the Keras model. If you add batchnorm to the Keras model, you might see an improvement in terms of how many epochs it takes to converge. It might also perform better with the larger dataset. PS. When you post an answer I don't get notified that you have replied - to notify me please leave a comment/vote on my post.

Comment: I added the BatchNormalization after each layer (and removed my previous normalization) and still it is slow and does not work. I read that PyTorch is much better for larger datasets. Maybe it is just that the problem. I think now I should learn PyTorch, thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. Not sure why the Keras version is not working as well. Maybe applying a new shuffle per epoch would make a difference, if it's not happening by default.